# jquery / html checkbox show div only for parent/targeted div, uncheck checkbox if another checkbox selected?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery to style the checkbox's in my form. The checkboxes are laid out as follows:

```
 --------        ---------
|        |       |       |
|        |       |       |
|_ _ _ _ |       |_ _ _ _|
```

so they appear as large boxes which change colour (orange) when a user checks them. However at the moment the user can select multiple checkboxes, and both boxes will become (orange). How can I uncheck a box in that group of check boxes if a user has more than one selected?

Also, when a checkbox if not checked my  is displayed. But when a user checks a checkbox my  is displayed.

The problem is if the user checks the left checkbox 'checkbox_tick2' is displayed in both checkboxes, and vice versa but I only want it to show for that target div/parent div that has been checked?

Can someone please show me how I could achieve this? Thanks

html:

```
<div class="select_box_outer">
    <div class="select_text">Yes</div>
    <div class="inner_draw">
    <span class="select_box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="select_box1" value="same">
    <div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
    <div class="checkbox_tick2"></div>
    </span>
    </div></div>


    <div class="select_box_outer">
    <div class="select_text">No</div>
    <div class="inner_draw">
    <span class="select_box">
    <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="select_box1" value="same">
    <div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
    <div class="checkbox_tick2"></div>
    </span>
    </div></div>
```

jquery:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
$(".select_box_outer").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("changeBackground");
});
});  
</script>
<script>
$(".select_box_outer").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
        $(".checkbox_tick2").css("display", "none");
        $(".checkbox_tick").css("display", "block");
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
        $(".checkbox_tick2").css("display", "block");
        $(".checkbox_tick").css("display", "none");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: That is why radio buttons are developed.

Comment: What @Jai said. You can style controls however you wish; even making radio buttons look like checkboxes. There are good reasons not to do that, though: users have learned that checkboxes mean "select one or more of these options"; radio buttons mean "select only one of these options". By violating that expectation, you're adding to your users' mental effort to use your site, making it harder for them to complete their tasks.